# Sending a CSV file using Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file-upload

I'm building a front end tool that allows users to upload a CSV file to a certain end point. I use the HTML5 input="file"

Here is my JSX, I use the React Dropzone library:

```
<Dropzone
  multiple={false}
  onDrop={this.onDrop}
>
  <div>
    <input type="file" />
  </div>
</Dropzone>
```

The onDrop function:

```
onDrop(acceptedFile) {
  this.setState({ file: acceptedFile });
}
```

I grab that file and put it on my state. My submit function looks like this:

```
submitFile() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('uploadCsv', this.state.file);
  fetch('/api/person/uploadfile', {
    body: formData,
    method: 'POST'
  });
}
```

It then goes through a few files for routing..

```
router.use('/person', require('./routers/personRoutes').default);
router.post('/uploadfile', fileUpload);
```

Then I run my fileUpload function:

```
export const fileUpload = post({
  route: req => {
    return `${BASE_URL}/v1/fileupload/persons`;
  }
});
```

Here I have no idea what to do. Usually I just have to return a URL and everything works. `req.body` is just an empty object - {}. The error message I get back says:

```
Current request is not a multipart request
```

BUT. Something as simple as this does work:

```
<html>
  <form action="http://localhost:9275/v1/fileupload/persons"
  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <p>
     Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
    <input type="file" name="file" size="40">
    </p>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>
</html>
```

I've looked all over stack overflow and none of solutions have helped thus far :( the coworker who wrote the node stuff left so I'm alone on this

Comment: Here is tutorial https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/ how you can do file uploading with Node

Comment: How do you set `this.state.file`?

Comment: I just edited the post to include everything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multipart request in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587342/multipart-request-in-node-js)

Comment: Did you ever get this answered?

Comment: @wuno yes I believe the answer was that I was not giving the upload name.. something along those lines